# Append a string inside loop in iOS

Tags: ios, loops, string-concatenation, nsmutablestring

I'm using below code to append a string received from server in for loop. I'm not able to figure it out what is going wrong. I'm receiving an empty string after appending.

**FileName.h**

```
    @interface Communicator : NSObject <NSStreamDelegate> 
    {
      ...
     NSMutableString *strServerResponse;

    }

    ...
    @property (nonatomic,strong)  NSMutableString *strServerResponse;
    @end
```

FileName.m

```
       @implementation Communicator

        @synthesize strServerResponse;

        ...

        -(void) setUp {

         strServerResponse = [NSMutableString string];
         ...
        }

        - (void)stream:(NSStream *)stream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)event {

            uint8_t buffer[1024];
            int len;

            while ([inputStream hasBytesAvailable]) {
                len = [inputStream read:buffer maxLength:sizeof(buffer)];
                if (len > 0) {

                 NSString *output = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:buffer length:len encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

                    if (nil != output) {
                      NSlog(@"output : ",output);
                      [strServerResponse appendString:output];
                    }
                }
             }


          NSLog(@"strServerResponse : %@", strServerResponse);
        } 

         ..
```

Log for strServerResponse is always empty. Where I'm going wrong? The 'Setup' methods in this file is invoked from other file. I have used debug and seen the flow is correct. Here 'Output' string prints correct Log. Below is screenshot for log.

[image: Edited server log]

Comment: What does `buffer` look like?  What is `len`?

Comment: How is your question more urgent than any other post?

Comment: Where's the for loop?

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe : I have deadline to meet today

Comment: @Droppy : buffer contains response on bytes format which is later converted to NSString.

Comment: @JayprakashDubey Please post the output from that `NSLog()` call, as it's causing confusion.

Comment: @Droppy : Log is posted in screenshot

Answer (score 1):

Your code is flawed in several ways but the reason for the problem at hand probably is that the server's response is not ASCII.

You should set a breakpoint in the line with the condition `if (nil != output)` and check if `output` is ever non-nil.

Comment: @JayprakashDubey Sorry, I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forget to call setup, so strServerResponse is not initialise.

Comment: In this case the console would not show an empty response but "`strServerResponse : (null)`"

Comment: Let me check..@JayprakashDubey

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the solution after three days of random effort. I changed **NSASCIIStringEncoding** to **NSUTF8StringEncoding** and that worked magic for me! I don't know how changing this can affect the result. Now, I'm getting result from server with last strings being retained in each loop.